# Where does the oxygen come from in the deployable breathing masks?

Tags: emergency, oxygen

I don't know what they are called. In case of emergency like smoke they deploy, but where do this oxygen come from.

Comment: As a side note, cabin masks are not typically deployed for smoke; they're not terribly useful (they just mix cabin air with some additional oxygen, so you'd still breathe in smoke) and they can be harmful (the generators get extremely hot, and they put more oxygen in the cabin which can fuel a fire). Flight crew masks are used for smoke, but they work differently and are able to supply 100% oxygen without any mixing with cabin air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oxygen is provided through [Chemical Oxygen Generators](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Chemical_Oxygen_Generators). Oxygen masks are triggered either automatically given certain conditions or by the flight crew.

> Oxygen generators are usually installed in above each seat row. If the cabin altitude reaches a predetermined height (14,000' is standard) or if the system is activated by the flight crew, overhead panels open and oxygen masks drop out. To put the mask on, it is necessary for the intending user to pull it down and this action releases the firing pin and activates the generator.
>
> The oxidizer core of an oxygen generator usually consists mainly of Sodium Chlorate (NaClO<sub>3</sub>) mixed with <5% Barium Peroxide (BaO<sub>2</sub>) and <1% Potassium Perchlorate (KClO<sub>4</sub>). This core is activated by the application of heat generated usually generated by a mixture of lead styphnate and tetracene which itself is activated by a small explosive charge in a percussion cap are a mixture. This explosive charge is set off by the release of a spring-loaded initiation mechanism which is restrained until released by a pull on the lanyard which is visible when oxygen masks are released from overhead panels. Once activated, the chemical reaction and production of oxygen will continue until the generator has been exhausted which is typically in the range 12 to 20 minutes.

Comment: You might want to edit the second sentence?  I know what you mean but it does read as if the generators are triggered automatically which is not the case.

Comment: @Simon You are right, my bad!

Comment: It depends. Some aircraft have pressurized oxygen bottles.